# Tags support is not enabled. You must use the flag "Yaml::PARSE_CUSTOM_TAGS" to use "!service_locator"

Tags: symfony

I am trying to add the [webpack-encore-bundle](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle) to my Drupal site, I have this in services.yml file:

```
services:
  webpack_encore.twig_entry_files_extension:
    class: Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Twig\EntryFilesTwigExtension
    arguments:
      ['@service_container']
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }

  webpack_encore.tag_renderer:
    class: Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Asset\TagRenderer
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.reset}
    arguments:
      ['@webpack_encore.entrypoint_lookup_collection', '@assets.packages']

  assets.packages:
    class: Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages

  webpack_encore.default_entrypoint:
    class: Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Asset\EntrypointLookup
    arguments:
      - 'web/themes/custom/mytheme_base/public/build/entrypoints.json'

  webpack_encore.entrypoint_lookup_collection:
    class: Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Asset\EntrypointLookupCollection
    arguments:
      - !service_locator
        _default: '@webpack_encore.default_entrypoint'
```

But I am getting this error:

```
In YamlSymfony.php line 40:
                                                                                                                                                
  Tags support is not enabled. You must use the flag "Yaml::PARSE_CUSTOM_TAGS" to use "!service_locator" at line 27 (near "!service_locator").  
                                                                                                                                                

In Parser.php line 1157:
                                                                                                                                                
  Tags support is not enabled. You must use the flag "Yaml::PARSE_CUSTOM_TAGS" to use "!service_locator" at line 27 (near "!service_locator").
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If using custom tags in your code : see Symfony documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/components/yaml.html#parsing-and-dumping-custom-tags

If you are getting this error when running `bin/console.php lint:yaml my/repository`, try running it with the option "--parse-tags" : `bin/console.php lint:yaml --parse-tags my/repository`